# Why is my script to remove spaces leaving one space?

Tags: python

I'm working on a beginner project to detect anagrams. Part of it is removing all the spaces from each word. To do this, I'm using

```
for i in list1:
        if(i == " "):
            list1.remove(i)

  for i in list2:
        if(i == " "):
            list2.remove(i)
```

It removes every space, except when two or more spaces are adjacent, and then it always leaves one space

Comment: You can achieve the same result with string.strip()

Comment: These are great recommendations, but they're still not addressing the underlying mechanism of the script that is failing OP.

Comment: @Yehuda, the dup that I linked to is addressing exactly the issue OP is facing.

Comment: Please, provide [mre], incl. sample input.

Comment: The problem is that when the ith element of list1 is removed, in the next iteration i+1 is being evaluated while it should re-evaluate the element i.

Comment: You should not modify a list you are iterating over within the looping block.  Best to build up a new list of what you want to save, or a list of indexes to delete, and delete them from highest to lowest in another loop.

Answer (score 1):

The issue origins from the fact that you're manipulating a list while iterating through it. When you delete a space at a certain index, the next character now becomes this index, but as your iterating you increment the index and therefore skip this character.

So you either have to iterate through the whole string and manipulate afterwards or also manipulate your iterator while iterating. The latter is not possible with `for i in list`.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this to solve the one space left issue:

```
list = [' hi', '   hello ', '  how   are    you']
d = []
for element in range(0,len(list)):
      d.append("".join(list[element].split()))
```

Comment: This may solves the issue but doesn't answer the question